# Table rows can never be more than 15

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I do not want the record to the table more than 15.

Scenario:
A new record is saved. If it were a record number of 16. The first record to be deleted.
How do I remove the first record?Can it be done automatically?

Comment: Yes you can use a trigger. Also consider timestamping the insert and hide the table behind a view that only selects the latest 15 records.

Answer (score 0):

if it is entity framework and you want to use a basic rule here it is

suppose your object is person and its set is called people

1. Before you do context.people.add(new person()) apply following logic
2. obtain count of people in database `context.people.count()`
3. check if this count is greater than 15 you can do this via single statment `if(context.people.count()>15)`
4. inside if you can write `people firstperson = context.people.OrderBy(x=>x.ID).First() or if you have date inserted or added you can use`.OrderBy(x => x.dateadded)`and pick the first element. Make sure you order it in correct way using`OrderBy`or`OrderByDescending`
5. place this record in a variable and call `context.remove(firstperson)` before you do `context.add(new person())`

If you are doing this in an empty table your ID's would increment but you can safely delete by ID order and pick the least one every time you delete.

Answer (score 0):

WITH A AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM    MyTable
        )
DELETE FROM A

The rows referenced in the TOP expression used with INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE are not arranged in any order.

Therefore, you better use WITH decision with ORDER BY clause, which will let you specify more exactly which row you consider to be the first.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a trigger and an identity column to ensure only the 15 most-recently-inserted rows are kept in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
     rowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,MyColumn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TG_MyTable_Only15
ON MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    WITH
            t1
                (
                     rowID
                )
            AS
                (
                    SELECT TOP 15
                     rowID
                    FROM MyTable
                    ORDER BY rowID DESC
                )
    DELETE FROM MyTable
    WHERE rowID NOT IN (SELECT rowID FROM t1)
END
GO
```